# Are rectangules bad for animating?

Tags: animation, topology

I'm creating a character and sometimes i have to use rectangles instead of squares, but i'm strongly trying to make everything with squares, unfortunately i have to use rectangles in some areas. i have a crisis right now while creating my character, thinking if i'm doing a bad topology work for animation because of the use of rectangles. So... are these bad for animation? (if so, what kind of problems involves using rectangles instead of squares on the topology of characters that are to be animated?)

Comment: Rectangles are usually ok, I wouldnt worry about it too much, You want to be careful and watch out for Triangles and NGONS (Has 5 or more sides) for animation. Unless your rectangle is abnormally long and the animation is trying to bend at that spot.